# Bronze badge for sharing?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badge-request, publicity-badges

Should we create a bronze badge on the public beta sites for helping to promote good questions from the sites with the new facebook/twitter links?  I'm thinking a little encouragement would go a long way, but I wouldn't want it to get abused (i.e. someone just shares a random question that isn't good to get the badge).

Comment: A badge on the beta site or on 51?

Comment: @waiwai933: The beta site...

Comment: *"Promoting good question from the public beta sites..."* I would think that is *outside* the purview of Area 51; a badge for the *site*, I would say.

Comment: -1, I don't think it's a good idea for the reasons you yourself and Robert pointed out :S

Answer (score 4):

This has been completed with the introduction of the [Announcer, Booster, and Publicist Badges](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/).

Answer (score 1):

You already get badge and reputation for referring people to commit for a website on Area51. Why would we need other badge for nearly the same exact thing ?

**The reputation you get on Area51**
Referred user with a confirmed email address commits to the proposal +5
Referred user participates in the beta  +25

**The badge you get on Area51**
(Silver Badge) Campaigner - Referred 25 committers to a proposal
(Bronze Badge) Lobbyist - First commitment referral
(Gold Badge) Activist - Referred 100 committers to a proposal

Answer (score 0):

In order for it not to be abused, we'd have to tie it to something else happening, beyond simply sharing with the buttons. Not sure what that is or could be.

For example, Student and Teacher both require 1 upvote on either a question or an answer respectively. We don't give the badges for simply *posting* a question or answer.

(yes, we do give a badge for filling out your profile page, and other one-off events like first upvote and first downvote.)

Comment: and yet you implemented it anyway.  GOOD JOB!

Comment: @power well the "something else" was "count the number of unique incoming IPs"..